# Give an example which proves/disproves the condition for convergence of the series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, divergent-series

Firstly I have these 2 conditions for arbitrary sequences {$x_n$}:

> Given any 1$\lt$q$\lt$p$\lt$ $\infty$, there is a real sequence
>   {$x_n$} such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{x_n}|^{p}$ is convergent but
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{x_n}|^{q}$ is divergent.

I need an example to prove/disprove this. I tried to think of the auxiliary series $\sum {1\over n^p}$. But I ended up nowhere. A better example which I should consider here?

The second case is:

> Given any 1$\lt$p$\lt$q$\lt$ $\infty$, there is a real sequence
>   {$x_n$} such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{x_n}|^{p}$ is convergent but
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{x_n}|^{q}$ is divergent.
>   I need an example to prove/disprove this as well.

Comment: doesn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/q}}$ work for the first case?

Comment: Have you tried playing with variations of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$? You’ll quickly find an example to each if you do. (Just try a few different values of $s$)

Comment: Oh yes! It does work. I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in the comments the first case has already been answered. So, I'll focus on the second one.

The most important part here is to know how the tail of your series behaves. For example, look at $p=1$ and $q=2$. The tail should converge quicker of the series where $q=2$ if the terms are below $1$. For example, $1/n^2$ converges slower than $1/n^4$ to $0$.

To make this idea precise, we know that in a convergent series the terms should converge to $0$. Hence, we can find an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$: $|x_n|<1$. And thus, the tail after $N$ is dominated by the $|x_n|^p$ series, since for all these $n$, we have $|x_n|^q < |x_n|^p$. Moreover, note that the convergence does not depend on the fixed finite first elements of the series $\{x_1,...,x_{N}\}$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Shatabdi Sinha:  You should not make changes to another's post that change its meaning.  If you feel that the post contains an error, post a Comment explaining your proposed correction.

Comment: It doesn't change the meaning at all. I suggested an obvious edit as the example taken above to explain the point went a bit off track in context of the condition given.